# how spark-java hot reload can be achieved

Tags: jetty, spark-java, hot-reload

I'm using spark-java with handlebars templates and i try to make embedded autoreload works for classes, hbs and css and other static files without success.

Can someone help me on this.

I simply start my sparkajav app with a Main class (not maven jetty plugin). I tried JVM parameters without any effect

Thks for help

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, Spark uses an embedded version of Jetty without using the WebApp/WAR concepts.

All of the hot reload features in Jetty are dependent on a WebApp/WAR to pay attention to, and trigger the hot reload (which in turn will close the isolated webapp classloader and properly perform the WebApp lifecycle destruction before redeploying the WebApp/WAR again).

Comment: So its not possible to do ?